# Can laser printer settings set from control panel be overridden by clients

Tags: network-printer

If I set, say output color to monochrome from my printer's control panel, will clients have the option from their local settings to change to color if needed?

Printer: Brother HL-3170CDW

Clients connect via Windows 7. It's a peer to peer setup.

Comment: What is the make and model of your printer? Normally this would be a no, but there are exceptions.

Comment: I added that info to OP

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think this printer works with presets and offer setting the settings to a default. Clients can override them at will. Because I'm not sure, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The answer depends on 1) How the clients are connected to the printer, and 2) Whether the printer driver permits settings defined on the print server to be overridden. So, how are the clients connecting to the printer? What OSes are involved?

Comment: I updated the OP

Comment: Down voting is fine but op has made edits to improve post so down votes should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

On the server, settings made in "Printing Preferences" will be the default values given to every computer that adds that printer.

You can then set permissions on the shared queue to prevent users from changing those defaults. I believe the permission you should **deny** is **Manage Printer**.